# Java inheritance problem. Calling subclass method inside superclass array does not compile

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class BaseClass and it has two subclasses C and D. I need to put objects of both C and D type into the array of BaseClass. The assignment works.
But if I call a method print() defined in C and D on the array it will not compile. I am missing something but search on the web or here did not answer my question.

My book says the chain of inheritance will do look for print() in C. 
If print() found in C use it. If not found in C go up to parent class.
How to fix?

According to the Java description the inheritance allows a subclass to inherit data and methods from the super class. Furthermore, in the inheritance it says that when a method is invoked on an object the JVM it will first look for the method in the class of the object. If the method is in there it will then use that method. However this following will not compile. The objective is to have an array of the superclass and assign to it objects of the subclasses.

The following is the program.

```
//This is an example program.
public class Tester
{
    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        BaseClass[] myarr = new BaseClass[10];
        myarr[0] = new C();
        myarr[1] = new D();

        myarr[0].print();  //error

        for (int i =0 ; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(myarr[i] != null)  myarr[i].print(); //will not compile. Why?
        }
    }
}
```

This is the superclass code.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
    }

    //it wants print(), why?
}
```

Next I have two subclasses C and D.

```
//subclass
public class C extends BaseClass
{
    public C()
    {
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(“hello C”);
    }
}
```

And subclass D.

```
//subclass
public class D extends BaseClass
{
    public D()
    {
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(“hello D”);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are asking your base class for things defined in two different subclasses. Where is the chain?

Comment: Sorry when I said chain I just meant one superclass and one subclass. Short chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because when creating an Array of Type BaseClass, the compiler does not know anything about a `print()` method. These just get introduced in your 2 subclasses.

Just imagine you had an other Subclass called `E` (also extending Baseclass) which did not have a `print()` function. Now assign an object of E to one of the places in `myarr`. Until here everything would work fine. Now when you try calling the `print()` method the compiler would not know what to do. This is why the compiler cannot find print() and does not want to 'interprete' your code.

Now to solve this there are 2 possibilities. If you want a `print()`-method in every Subclass you could simply create one abstract method:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public BaseClass() {
        // Some Constructor Work
    }
    // This tells the compiler there is a print()-method in every subclass because it must be overridden
    public abstract void print();
}
```

Now in your Subclasses (I just do one for proof of concept :)):

```
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    public SubClass() {
        // Do Constructor Work if necessary
    }
    // I would highly suggest you also use this annotation because it helps you 
    // identifying overridden methods (but it is not obligatory to use)
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Hello from SubClass");
    }
}
```

Now in your main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Init Array
    BaseClass[] myarr = new BaseClass[4];
    myarr[0] = new SubClass();
    myarr[1] = new OtherSubClass();
    // and so on... I think you get the gist

    // Now execute print()
    myarr[0].print(); // This works perfectly now.
}
```

Now possibility 2 which depending on your usecase could be the only working one (though I would highly recommend to use the technique shown before as here you must be 100% certain which ClassType your object is) is a lot unsafer and you must know what you are doing or you get errors (and noone likes errors right? :)): Use Casting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // Note I will be using "your" classes here again
    // Array Init...
    BaseClass[] myarr = new BaseClass[10];
    // Assign blabla
    myarr[0] = new C();
    myarr[1] = new D();

    ((C) myarr[0]).print(); // Casting to C-Type which has a print()
}
```

This will basically tell the compiler (and the JVM): "Hey don't care about what type this object is. Just assume it would be a C-Type!"
I think you start to realize what could be the problem. If the compiler wants to read a C-Type but instead gets a D-Type or an E-Type it does not know what to do --> Error.

Hope I could help you :)

EDIT:

Ah and note that by adding the abstract modifier to a class you cannot create an object of this class any more, just of the corresponding children-classes. This is why I also wanted to give you possibility 2 as this is more versatile.

Comment: I will try summarize the answers what I learned and if somebody sees an error please correct me.  I think I understand that the compiler does not run the program and therefore it does not know what is the actual dynamic type of the object inside the myarr[0]. The compiler only says, the static type of myarr[0] is BaseClass and BaseClass is missing the method print(). So compiler says error.

Comment: Continue. Now during runtime, the execution knows exactly what dynamic type the myarr[0] has, in my case it has dynamic type class C. Now the execution will say myarr[0] is type C. Type C has its own method print(). So actually the run time does not care if the BaseClass has print() or not. The run time does not consult the BaseClass print().

Comment: Sounds more or less accurate. At least this is how you can picture it. The compiler and JVM are 2 very complicated topics and to truely understand them it takes time...
Just one thing I would say is a little different. During Runtime the JVM stores the basic type of the array. In this case BaseClass. Neither does it know about how many C's nor how many D's were saved. The only time it DOES know what is going on is while casting to C-Type.

BTW: I would appreciate if you accept an answer to close this question :)

Answer (score 1):

At compile time, the compiler will check to see that BaseClass has a print() method since the static type of any element in myarr is BaseClass. At runtime, the program will be able to dynamically resolve the type of each object to either C or D. Only then will it look at the C or D classes for their respective print methods. To fix this, you could add a default print method in BaseClass.

Comment: Or an `abstract` method in `BaseClass`.  Then you don't need some dummy implementation that will never be executed.